# upgrade to 5.49 on Wordpress unzip and file permissions

Tags: upgrade, permissions

In following the instructions for upgrading on a wordpress cms (https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/upgrade/wordpress/), I backed up all the existing files and renamed the existing civicrm directory incase I have to restore a working copy.  I have not deleted the old folder YET.

I loaded the new 5.49.1 zip file and unpacked it into the wp-content/plugins directory which creates a new civicrm folder and underlying folders & files. When I compare the file permissions for each of the newly unpacked folders and files, the new folder and file permissions don't match the file permissions in my currently working set of files & directories.

Can I just go ahead and follow the upgrade instructions from this point, or do I have to be concerned that things will become corrupted and I will have created the biggest headache ever?  Or do I have to go through each folder and set the permissions?

Comment: Could you please edit your question to show the actual differences between the file permissions - including whether the files are owned by different users?  it may be nothing, or it may be important.

Answer (score 1):

Did you just rename it or move it completely out of the tree? I'd move it completely out otherwise it might think there are two conflicting copies even with different names.

For permissions, you'd probably want to make it match the previous if it was working before. But in general the below will usually make it "sane" unless the server setup is unusual:

```
cd civicrm
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 \{\} \;
find . -type d -exec chmod 755 \{\} \;
```